# How to share selected app invite friend message flutter? using share plugin

Tags: flutter

I'm currently developing a chat app that allows the invite Friend to share a message to certain selected apps

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `share_plus` package.
https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus

Eg:

```
Share.share('check out my website https://example.com', subject: 'Look what I made!');
```

Comment: share_plus  plugin share our device all apps but I need is only share to messaging apps like  chatting apps , SMS and e-mail only